# How can I see whether the last Microsoft Windows 10 restart was caused by Windows update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

How can I see whether the last Microsoft Windows 10 restart was caused by Windows update?

I use Microsoft Windows 18.03 "Professional".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78335-read-shutdown-logs-event-viewer-windows.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624001758/https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78335-read-shutdown-logs-event-viewer-windows.html)):

1. Press the Win+R keys to open Run, type eventvwr.msc into Run, and click/tap on OK to open Event Viewer.
2. In the left pane of Event Viewer, open Windows Logs -> System, right click or press and hold on System, and click/tap on Filter Current Log.

   If you have already filtered this log, click/tap on Clear Filter first and then click/tap on Filter Current Log to start over fresh.
3. Enter the event IDs `1074, 6006, 6008` into the  field, and click/tap on OK.
4. You can now view the details of these shutdown event logs filtered by these event IDs.
5. When finished viewing log details, you can close Event Viewer if you like.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Why is the image orange?

Comment: @Ramhound f.lux